# Is the converse of the definition of the injective function valid?

Tags: functions

The injective function is defined as.

$$\forall a,b \in X, f(a) = f(b) \implies a = b$$

Why is it not defined with a biconditional operator like this?

$$\forall a,b \in X, f(a) = f(b) \iff  a = b$$

Since it is not defined with this operator I assume that
$$\neg(\forall a,b \in X, a = b \implies f(a) = (b))$$

But why?

Comment: Your bidirectional arrow directly follows from the definition of function.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can define it with $\Leftrightarrow$, since the reverse way ($\Leftarrow$) is always true.

But it is precisely because the reverse way is always true that there is not point in adding it in the definition.